# Set ValidationError from code most simple way

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, xaml, combobox

In this typical situation we have some dialogs that takes a user through a configure wizard. In one of those dialog steps we have a ComboBox with advanced objects. When `SelectionChanged` event raises we do all the necessary code to save the option of the user. So far no problems and works like a charm.

Now the think we are stuck at is when the user configures all UI elements in the dialog except this one (no value selected) we want to raise a `ValidationError` when the user clicks next. Just like many forms on website's do. You fill in the form, hit submit and than `ValidationErrors` are raised.

We want the same way but since there is no binding it seems we cannot get it to work. Normally we use `iDataError` but in this case it doesn't with.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cbMyComboBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Width="250"
    Margin="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Code behind:

```
Private Async Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If cbMyComboBox.SelectedIndex < 0 Then

        '---->> Here lies the problem BindingExpression is always nothing? <<----
        Dim be As BindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(cbMyComboBox, ComboBox.TextProperty)

        Dim validationError As ValidationError = New ValidationError(New DataErrorValidationRule(), be)
        validationError.ErrorContent = "Please select a value bla bla bla"
        Validation.MarkInvalid(be, validationError)

        'Somewhere else we remove the ValidationError when user selects a value
    Else
        'Next step
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If there is no binding, you won't get a `BindingExpression` back from the `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` method.

Comment: WPF data validation is based on the binding engine. If you chose to not use data binding (for what ever reason), you must manually handle the visual feedback. You can wrap the ComboBox in an error Border and toggle its visibility on failing validation. You can use a Popup to display messages. You can move it to a reusable wrapper control with a ContentPresenter to host the actual control. Data binding has many advantages. Build-in data vaslidation is only one. Now your left to implement you own validation infrastructure instead of adding a property to your control and bind it to the ComboBox..

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I ended up with a simple binding where i bind the `SelectedValue` to the `TagProperty` now it works. The only thing now that is going wrong is that the popup isn't shown unless i however the mouse over or click on the `ComboBox` Any idea about that?